# Disable a Javascript function during runtime

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm working on a web portal platform where the javascript is added through a helper dialog on the page itself.

I accidentally added a Javascript line of code that has now disabled the helper dialog. I don't have easy access to the script files on the backend.

I can set a debug breakpoint on the bad line in Firefox (I didn't get the breakpoint working in Chrome or Safari since it was inline in the html), but I can not find any way to prevent that line of code or function to be executed.

How can I prevent a function called MyBadFunction() to be executed whilst debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reassign the function name to do nothing. Type this into the console:

```
MyBadFunction = function() {};
```

Comment: I can verify that this worked perfectly and fixed the problem.